# Xampp, Apache: I have a problem running apache. How to make PID different PID 1908?

Tags: apache, xampp

[image: enter image netstat here]

Xampp, Apache: I have a problem running apache. How to make PID different PID 1908?

[image: enter image xampp here]

Comment: Please [edit] your question instead of writing additional information as comments

Comment: PID is allocated by the operating system. Shutdown and restart the service to get a new PID. This will answer your question, but likely not solve your problem. You should do what the message says: "Check the Windows Event Viewer for more clues..." and search for those message to solve the underlying problem